# How to limit Message consumption rate of Kafka Consumer in SpringBoot? (Kafka Stream)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I want to limit my Kafka Consumer message consumption rate to 1 Message per 10 seconds .I'm using kafka streams in Spring boot .

Following is the property I tried to Make this work but it didn't worked out s expected(Consumed many messages at once).

```
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokersUrl);
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
         //
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,1);
         config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
```

is there any way to Manually ACK(Manual offsetCommits) in KafkaStreams? which will be usefull to control the msg consumption rate .

Please note that i'm using Kstreams(KafkaStreams)
Any help is really appreciated . :)

Comment: Did you try adding prefix `spring.kafka.streams.properties` to that?

Comment: I believe since ack mode is auto (managed by streams itself) , if auto ack is gonna happen  in let's say 10 ms then it will over ride the time given in max.poll.interval.ms . if this is true , then can anyone tell me how to manually give ack in kafka streams?

Comment: YAML/properties doesn't matter. You should be using auto-wired properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: I'm doing that pal . 
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokersUrl);
  config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
   config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
   //
   config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,1);
   config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10000);

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Using Spring properties as defined in that link will do `config.put` _automatically_ (i.e. "autowired"), so you don't need to do that in code. In any case, you should look at the logs to see what actually gets applied... You could also use `config.put(consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.[VALUE], x))` for setting consumer properties in streams apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achieved the desired message consumption limit using `Thread.sleep()`.
Since there is no way to control the message consumption rate using Kafka config properties, I had to use my application code to control the rate of consumption.

**Example**: If I want to set the record consumption rate to say, `4 msg per 10 seconds` then I will consume 4 messages (keeping a count in parallel). Once 4 records are consumed, then I will make the thread sleep for 10 seconds and will repeat the same process over again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what `MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG` actually does.

That is the max *allowed* time for the client to read an event.

From docs

> controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer will proactively leave the group (5 minutes by default). The value of the configuration `request.timeout.ms` (default to 30 seconds) must always be smaller than `max.poll.interval.ms`(default to 5 minutes), since that is the maximum time that a JoinGroup request can block on the server while the consumer is rebalance

"maximum time" not saying any "delay" between poll invocations.

Kafka Streams will constantly poll; you cannot easily pause/start it and delay record polling.

To read an event every 10 seconds without losing consumers in the group due to lost heartbeats, then you should use Consumer API, with `pause()` method, call `Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(10))`, then `resume()` + `poll()` while setting `max.poll.records=1`

Comment: So , you mean there is no way to control the message consumption rate in Kafka Streams ? if "yes" then... is there any way to manually ack in Kstreams ? which  i can use to control the msg consumption rate .

Comment: You can control the number of records polled, sure. You can set the timeout that it takes for those to be polled, yes. You cannot, however, only get "one record **per T time**" since it will always be polling... `acks` is a producer property, so I dont understand second part

Comment: Generally when i was using Spring kafka Consumer , we can control the offset Commits . so , if i try to manually commit the offset using my application rather than auto commit then let's say using my application i make manual offset commit of currently consumed msg after 10 secs . I will achieve "1 msg per T time " likewise i'm asking , is it possible in kafka streams?

Comment: There is no way to manually commit in Streams API, no